# Read a CSV file or make a MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I'm making a CMS where once a user searches for something a cache file (CSV) is generated using MySQL and after that the same CSV is included and served by PHP for the same search.

Now I want to allow users to filter data from that same cache/static file using jQuery.

I have two options of

1. Make a DB query to generate the result based on user's filter parameters
2. Read that cache/static (which is in CSV format) and generate the result based on user's parameters using PHP only.

Both my Database and CSV files are small about 2000 rows in the MySQL Database and Max 500 lines in a CSV file. Average length of the CSV file would be around 50 lines. There will be several(say about 100) CSV files for diferrent searches.

Which technique will be faster and efficient? I'm on a shared host.

Search results are like product information on eCommerce websites.

Comment: 2000 rows? just give them all to the client and let javascript sort it out.

Comment: 2000 products on a single page? it will make a infinity scroll.

Comment: I didn't say *display* 2000 results. Just give them to javascript and let it filter/paginate. You said yourself that some results will have 500 records, and 2000 isnt even an order of magnitude greater than 500. 2000 records is nothing(ive done 30k - youd be surprised how well it works). obviously give it to the client as json, not csv.

Comment: That seems interesting. I will try this for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL servers in shared hosts context are most of the time ridiculously overloaded and may be very slow / unresponding sometimes.

If you want a work around, you could make your php script create a CSV file from the data table for the first user of the day, then read the CSV file for the rest of the day.

Answer (score 0):

Because of you're on a shared host, total number 2K is not a problem, but the IO of harddisk is.

Put the database search results in memeory, such as mysql memeory engine table, 
let redis manages the cache with TTL is better.